# Pass variable to subroutine with different re-action based on the variable past

Tags: perl

So lets say I have the following sub-routine which I use to validate user submitted variables. I want to condense the code down as much as possible and use the sub-routine to check all user supplied variables, but each variable passed to the routine will need to be check against a different regex based on what it was prior to the passing as an arguement.

```
sub mySubroutine
{
    # Get passed arguments
    my ($unknown) = @_;

    while ($unknown !~ m/^\d{3,6}$/) {    # Check for valid integer.
       # Does Stuff
    }
    return $unknown;

}

my $name = Bob;
mySubroutine($name);
...
my $age = 20;
mySubroutine($age);
```

What would be the best way to identify which regex it needs to be compared against. i.e. check $age passed into $unknown against digit only regex, but check $name also passed to $unknown against a string regex.

I am thinking I need to use an additional variable like $type as what is being passed then check that against a dispatch table, but then I would have to pass two variables each time. Is there a way for a subroutine to see what the variable was names that is passed to it from the main namespace?

I don't think this is worded all that well, so please let me know if I need to elaborate or rephrase.

Comment: function should return the variable if it passes the validation regexes or die if no match was found. The goal is to be able to put all the validation in one sub-routine so I can port it into a module and recycle later. I will have all different "types" of variables so recycling where possible seems to be a good way to go. I will most likely do with a dispatch table, but really just wanted some ideas, plus if you can validate the variable in the main namespace and check based on that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
sub mySubroutine
{
    # Get passed arguments
    my (%args) = @_;
    my $regexes = (
        age  => qr/.../,
        name => qr/.../,
    );

    foreach my $key in (%args)
    {
        if (%args{$key} !~ /$regexes{$key}/)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}

my $name = Bob;
mySubroutine(name => $name);
...
my $age = 20;
mySubroutine(age => $age);
mySubroutine(age => $age, name => $name, );
```

That way you can solve this, without jumping through too many hoops...
You could in %regexes use array references, if more than one test is necessary, or hash references, if you want to add an error message to each test and then loop through those...
the %regexes hash (or better a reference to it) could also be part of the parameters...

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the regex to the subroutine, something like:

```
sub mySubroutine {
    my ($reg, $str) = @_;
    if ($str =~ $reg) {
        return $str;
    } else {
        say "invalid string: $str";
        return 0;
    }
}

my $name = 'Bob';
# put in the regex all characters you want for a valid name !!!
$name = mySubroutine(qr/^[a-zA-Z' -]+$/,$name);
say $name;
$name = '123';
$name = mySubroutine(qr/^[a-zA-Z' -]+$/,$name);
say $name;
my $age = 20;
$age = mySubroutine(qr/^\d{1,3}$/, $age);
say $age;
$age = 'hgj';
$age = mySubroutine(qr/^\d{1,3}$/, $age);
say $age;
```

**output:**

```
Bob
invalid string: 123
0
20
invalid string: hgj
0
```